# Wireless connected but no connection

Tags: fedora, wifi

I'm running *Fedora 22*, *4.1.4-200.fc22.x86_64* and I'm not able to access the network through the wireless. This issue started recently and it happens at random times with random wireless networks.
Pinging IP addresses from the network (the router) or the internet results in about 95-99% failure rate.

I manage to connect to the WiFi but I have no internet connection. Or it connects with a **?** over the icon.
I know the problem is not with the network because all other devices work fine.

I also tried different kernel versions and same behavior persists.

Any idea where I should start from?

### Edit 1

It is a *Toshiba Satellite E45t-A4100* laptop about one year old.

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c170]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

### Edit 2

This is the message output by `dmesg`:

```
[ 9971.202675] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: No association and the time event is over already...
[ 9971.202697] wlp3s0: Connection to AP ca:3d:c7:94:29:f4 lost
[ 9971.229069] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 9971.232324] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 9971.232330] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 9971.232332] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 9971.232336] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.232339] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.232342] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.232345] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.232349] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9971.232351] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9971.232354] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.232357] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.232382] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 9971.235771] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 9971.235777] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
[ 9971.235779] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 9971.235783] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.235787] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.235790] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9971.235794] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[ 9971.235796] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 9971.235799] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
```

Comment: How old is the laptop (?) you're using? Does this happen if you plug in a new(ish) USB writeless card? I'm told that the low-noise amplifiers on wireless cards can degrade with time.

Comment: what chipset is wireless? what do the logs say? have you tried try reinstalling the drivers...or replace hard drive and install another distro to if it happens.

Comment: What are the outputs of `iwconfig` (to verify connection), `ifconfig` (to verify ip address), and either `sudo ip route` or `sudo route` (to verify correct routing)?  It could be a simple routing- or dhcp-type problem instead of a hardware or driver problem.